# send data from html form to skydrive excel sheet

Tags: php, javascript, html, cloud, onedrive

I want to send data from my basic html form to a public excel sheet in cloud (for example skydrive). How do i achieve this connectivity between the excel sheet and the html form?

Comment: You have more then 100 reputation so i assume that you should know how to ask a question ... Enhance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) to read an existing Excel file and add new information to it, then save it back to skydrive.

To save the file into the could you should mount the storage as a local folder/drive on your computer. For skydrive: On Windows it looks something like [this](http://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0000659.htm) and for a Unix system you can use [SMEStorage](http://www.rubynginx.com/index.php/2012/09/27/installing-skydrive/).